# Hermite Polynomials are orthonormal basis for $L(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-transform, hermite-polynomials

In the process of showing Hermite polynomials are dense in  $L^2(\Bbb{R})$, I asked to claim for $g \in L^2(R)$ (We may assume $g$ to be continuous)

- $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t) e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} \frac{\sin
     a(t-y)}{t-y} dt =0,\forall a,y\in \Bbb{R}$

  then $g$ is identically zero on $\Bbb{R}$.

I have no idea what the integral means and how to conclude the claim. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm not sure this answer works since I never had to really use the $e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$. If my argument is correct, I'm sure it's lacking rigor. I leave it to you to fill in the details since this seems like a homework question.

I'm going to take $a > 0$. Define 
$$f(t) = g(t)e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$$ 
and 
$$h(t) = \frac{\sin at}{t} = a \, \text{sinc}(at)$$
Then, by definition, the integral is $(f * h)(y)$, where $f * h$ denotes the convolution of $f$ and $h$. By the convolution theorem, $\mathcal{F}\{f*h\} = \mathcal{F}\{f\} \mathcal{F}\{h\}$.

We have
$$
\mathcal{F}\{h\}(x) = a \mathcal{F}\{t \mapsto \text{sinc}(at)\}(x) = \text{rect}\left(\frac{x}{ka} \right)
$$
for some constant $k$ (I don't know what convention you're using for the fourier transform).

On the other hand, we are given that $f * h = 0$. This is just the statement that the integral is $0$ for all choices of $y$. Thus $\mathcal{F}\{f * h\} = \mathcal{F}\{0\} = 0$. Therefore
$$
0 = \left(\mathcal{F}\{f\}(x)\right) \cdot \text{rect} \left(\frac{x}{ka}\right)
$$
for all choices of $a > 0$. This shows that $\mathcal{F}\{f\}$ is $0$ on the interval $\left[-\frac{ka}{2}, \frac{ka}{2} \right]$. But since we can take $a$ as large as we like, this shows that $\mathcal{F}\{f\}$ itself is identically $0$. But every function in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with a Fourier transform of $0$ is equivalent to $0$. Thus, we conclude that $f = 0$, which shows that $g = 0$ since $e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$ is positive on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user527939, could you, please, show some signs of life and ask a few more questions regarding this to see whether you understand this answer or not? It would be nice if the user who spent his time explaining knew his answer really was helpful and if there is sth he could add in order to explain all your confusions and, at the end, see if you really read his answer because there is no point in blindly accepting answers without any dialog. The point is for you to understand since you wrote you didn't know what the integral means.

Comment: When there are multiple answers, it's quite common people accept the first ones that are sometimes incorrect. Would you be able to see some answer is wrong an accept, particularly, this correct one? This is the reason why the users should investigate more on their own before asking. I could've post an answer before Charles Hudgins and it might had been incorrect. Do you understand the point?